# how to replace a line of two words in a file using python

Tags: python

I want to replace a line in a file but my code doesn't do what I want. The code doesn't change that line. It seems that the problem is the space between ALS and 4277 characters in the input.txt. I need to keep that space in the file. How can I fix my code?

**A part part of input.txt:**

```
ALS              4277
```

**Related part of the code:**

```
        for lines in fileinput.input('input.txt', inplace=True): 
            print(lines.rstrip().replace("ALS"+str(4277), "KLM" + str(4945)))
```

**Desired output:**

```
KLM              4945
```

Comment: You need to account for the spaces. `"ALS"+str(4277)` is the same as `"ALS4277"`

Comment: This space is different for different input files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the spaces vary you will need to use regex to account for the spaces.

```
import re

lines = "ALS              4277    "
line = re.sub(r"(ALS\s+4277)", "KLM              4945", lines.rstrip())

print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the same idea that other user have already pointed out, you could also reproduce the same spacing, by first matching the spacing and saving it in a variable (`spacing` in my code):

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()

match = re.match(r'ALS(\s+)4277', lines)
if match != None:
    spacing = match.group(1)
    lines = re.sub(r'ALS\s+4277', 'KLM%s4945'%spacing, lines.rstrip())

print lines
```

Comment: I thought about doing this: `spaces = " " * 14` then `"KLM%s4945" % spaces` to make the spaces consistent.

Comment: Ha, I swear this question has changed since I answered it.

Comment: Don't know about the question being changed - I really don't remember whether the OP stated that she/he wanted to keep the spaces or not. I just thought the spaces might vary, so maybe it would be easier to "automatize" the task :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b = line.strip().split()
        if a == 'ALS' and b == '4277':
            line = line.replace(a, 'KLM').replace(b, '4945')
        print(line, end='') # as line has '\n'
```